# How can I make my dialogflow agent to speak a number sequence in number format rather than thousands format

Tags: dialogflow-es

I am asking my agent for my wifi password which is for example 9876, then dialogflow responds by saying 'nine thousand eight hundred seventy six' rather than telling 'nine eight seven six(simple number format)'. I tried with spaces between numbers which is working fine but how can i achieve it without including spaces between numbers?

Comment: Identify the number as @sys.number-sequence. The output format will be string, not number.

Comment: But I am getting that response from another application through webhook and I used agent.add() function to give that respone to dialogflow agent. If it is a slot value then @sys.number-sequence will be solution but how can i achieve it if the process follows above methodology.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to change the default responses given by Dialogflow you can have a look into SSML. With SSML you can modify complete or parts of the response of your bot.

In your case you should have a look into the [say-as](https://developers.google.com/assistant/actions/reference/ssml#say%E2%80%91as) property to change just the number output.

To get the result that you want using the code "example 9876", your ssml string should look like this:

```
<speak>
  example <say-as interpret-as="verbatim">9876</say-as>
</speak>
```

This will translate into: "Example nine eight seven six".

If you are using Actions on Google, you can play around with SSML in the simulator under the audio tab and test what certain SSML tags fit your desired result.